# How to write a program that stops the shutdown process by C?

Tags: c, winapi, shutdown, application-shutdown, system-shutdown

Programs like Notepad can stop the computer shutdown process when files are not saved. How can I write a program that stops the shutdown process (in C)?

Comment: You mean the "These programs are preventing Windows from shutting down" screen?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376877(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If you need to support XP, then have a look at [WM_QUESRYENDSESSION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376890(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Start with the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376882(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows Vista and above there exists a fuction defined in User32.dll (User32.lib) called "ShutdownBlockReasonCreate". 
It takes two parameters: 
  **-** A handle of the window
  **-** A string representing a message to be displayed
If the call succeeds than you application will block windows from shutting down.

This is a powerful function and should not be abused!

Comment: I don't have time to test it nowadays. But, this answer seems reasonable.